# JBPM dashboard-builder app wont't start

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jbpm

I deployed dashboard-builder-6.1.0.Final.war app in Tomcat 8.0.11 and JRE 1.8.0_20.
Initially there was ClassNotFoundException which is good, I found required dependencies and gave them to it. In my case were slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar and cdi-api-1.2.jar.

Unfortunately got something even more confusing when try to open JBPM dashboard via http://myhost.com:8080/dashboard-builder/ :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 162

159: 
160:     <div id="login-content">
161:         <%
162:             LocaleManager localeManager = LocaleManager.lookup();
163:             Locale currentLocale =  localeManager.getCurrentLocale();
164:             SessionInitializer.PreferredLocale preferredLocale =  SessionInitializer.getPreferredLocale(request);
165:             if (preferredLocale != null) currentLocale = preferredLocale.asLocale();


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.jboss.dashboard.commons.cdi.CDIBeanLocator.getBeanByName(CDIBeanLocator.java:50)
    org.jboss.dashboard.LocaleManager.lookup(LocaleManager.java:37)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:214)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I really don't see a reason for that. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the tomcat distribution?  Have you followed https://github.com/droolsjbpm/dashboard-builder/blob/master/builder/src/main/tomcat7/README.md ?